# Вывод трех знаков после запятой

Tags: c#

Есть переменная типа double d = 1.5997, подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести три знака после запятой не округляя его?
Пробовал `Console.WriteLine("{0:0.###}", d);` Возвращает 1.6.
Пробовал `Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000}", d);` Возвращает 1.600,
а нужно 1.599.

Comment: Это не "не округляя", а "округляя в меньшую сторону".

Comment: @rdorn, а если четыре знака после запятой, отнимать 0,00005? Должно быть проще.

Comment: @rdorn, еще один минус, если у нас число 1.0007, то результат вернется 1.000, желательно 1, без нулей.

Comment: @rdorn, Round в этой перегрузке вернет 1.6.

Comment: да, похоже выбор действительно не велик... удалил неактуальные комментарии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой костыль поможет. `precision` - требуемое число знаков после запятой

```
static double myRound(double x, int precision)
{
    return ((int)(x * Math.Pow(10.0, precision)) / Math.Pow(10.0, precision));
}
```

Comment: тут проще что-то должно быть.

Comment: @Джирайя ну, пожелаю Вам удачи в поисках более простого :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот менее уневерсальный вариант но более быстрый.

```
Math.Truncate(1000 * 1.5997) / 1000; // 1,599
```

Comment: а если четыре знака после запятой?  *10000, /10000, что-то универсальное должно быть.

Comment: @Джирайя. универсально в ответе Exodium. Ты определись, тебе нужно проще, или универсальнее

Answer (score 1):

небольшая манипуляция должна решить ваш вопрос.

```
public double ReformatDouble (double num)
        {
            string number = num.ToString();
            string[] array = number.Split('.');
            string newNum = array[0].ToString() + "." + array[1].Substring(0, 3).ToString();

            return Double.Parse(newNum);
        }


ReformatDouble(1.12345);

//результат 1.123
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String.Format("{0:0.000}", 140.6767554); // "140.676"
```

Comment: `1,600` выдает ваш способ

Comment: @tCode Странно почему в примерах такой результат показан именно так, а `String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"` округлит до целых

Comment: проверил, реально 1,600

Comment: @tCode Заинтриговали сейчас лично гляну.

Comment: @Ethernets, _в примерах такой результат показан именно так_ - добавь ссылку на эти примеры

Comment: @Grundy Да действительно я был не прав, пример который я привел выше был взят с EN stackoverflow уже не найду где, на msdn ситуация по данному вопросу состоит иначе. Единственное что можно сделать так это написать что-то вроде: `var result = $"{140..6767554 - 0.0005:F3}";`